# How do I find the absolute minimum and maximum of a function on the giving interval using Wolfram Mathematica program?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, derivative, calculus

I know how to find the derivatives however i don’t know how to use mathematica to find the absolute value.  And compare with the graph and 2nd Derivatives?
f(x) = 3x^(2/3) -2x +1 on [-1,8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
f[x_] := 3 x^(2/3) - 2 x + 1
max = First@FindMaximum[{f[x], -1 <= x <= 8}, x];
min = First@FindMinimum[{f[x], -1 <= x <= 8}, x];
Plot[{f[x], f''[x], max, min}, {x, -1, 8},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get that solution?

Comment: See the documentation for [FindMaximum](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) and [Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).